# Change bottom navigation item state on backpress from activity to home fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

hello great community I have an app in which I am using bottom navigation with 4 fragments. to move to the last fragment the user must be logged in so when a new user open the app and tap on item 4 a login activity open.
the problem is when I backpress from login activity it moves me to the home fragment 1 which is ok but the state of the bottom navigation item doesn't changes the fragment 4 remain highlighted. so how to manage it that when I return back from the login activity the home fragment item should be highlighted.

[image: 1st fragment]

[image: moved to login activity]  [

[image: returent from login to home but bottom item shows 4th item]

this is my BottomNAvigation main activity

```
public class Bottom_Nav extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

SparseArray<Fragment> myFragments;
String user_type;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom__nav);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("DataStore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user_type = sharedPreferences.getString("user_type", "");


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    Nav_Helper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

    //make array to avoid re creating of fragments
    myFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    //loading the default fragment
    loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

    //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    //switching fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.navigation_home) {

            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            myFragments.put(1, fragment);


        loadFragment(fragment);

    } else if (id == R.id.navigation_use) {

        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();



                switch (user_type) {
                    case "detailer":

                        fragment = new Detailer_Zone();
                        myFragments.put(4, fragment);
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        break;
                    case "customer":

                        fragment = new Customer_Zone();
                        myFragments.put(4, fragment);
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        break;
                    case "empty":

                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }

            }


    else if (id == R.id.navigation_search) {
        // get cached instance of the fragment
        fragment = myFragments.get(2);

        // if fragment doesn't exist in myFragments, create one and add to it
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new SearchFragment();
            myFragments.put(2, fragment);
        }

        loadFragment(fragment);

    } else if (id == R.id.navigation_map) {
        // get cached instance of the fragment
        fragment = myFragments.get(3);

        // if fragment doesn't exist in myFragments, create one and add to it
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new MapsActivity();
            myFragments.put(3, fragment);
        }

        loadFragment(fragment);

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: map you `onBackpress()` with your logic.

Comment: @Jaymin how to call public onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) from here to change the state of the bottom menu??

Comment: post your code..

Comment: @pmms, Use `startActivityForResult` and return `RESULT_CANCELED` when user press back button and handle the case in `onActivityResult()` method from `Bottom_Nav` activity.

Comment: @Jaymin can you please add some code snippet for it

Comment: @JacobCelestine do you have any solution to suggest??

Comment: How is it that you return to HomeFragment? Do you use an Intent after login has succeeded? Or does it just finish and go back to the last stacktrace page?

Answer (score 0):

**Case for Login:**

```
 case "empty": 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login_Activity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent , 101);
        break;
```

**Login activity:**
 
When user click on back button execute below code.

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
finish();
```

**Handle case in `Bottom_Nav`** activity :

```
  // This method is called when the second activity finishes 
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // check that it is the SecondActivity with an OK result 
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

           onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem)
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: how to pass my menu item id or name to onNavigationSelected(?)  it gives error with this onNavigationItemSelected(R.id.navigation_home);

Comment: android.view.MenuItem cannot to be applied to (int)

Answer (score 0):

Try this work around. Replace your `case "empty":` with this:

```
case "empty":
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
```

Tell me if this works.